# shinyApp not displaying filtered data when switching between data frames

Tags: r, shiny, filtering

I'm working on creating a Shiny app where I can toggle between two datasets containing country data and filter using different values. The catch is that the two datasets, although identical, are in different languages (dat_en=English and dat_fr=French). This means that not only the contents of the data are in different languages, but the column names are too. I think I have the toggling down fine. However, I can't see the unfiltered data displayed in the mainPanel nor can I see any of the filtered data once I select from the filters.

I created a version of this code using just the English data, and I used DT to display the filtered data; it worked just fine. Here is a portion of that old code:

```
#UI
ui <- shinyUI(
  
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("subject", "Subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$Subject, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("year", "Year by Item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$`Year by Item`, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    selectInput("geo_units", "Geographic units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$`Geographic units`, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
    
DT::DTOutput('ex1')
    
  )
  
)

#SERVER 
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$Subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
    updateSelectInput(session, "year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$`Year by Item`, ", "))))), selected = input$year)
    updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat$`Geographic units`, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
    
    filtered_dat <- dat
    
    if(!is.null(input$subject)) {
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$Subject, ", "), function(x) any(input$subject %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$`Year by Item`, ", "))))), selected = input$year)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$`Geographic units`, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
    }
    
    if(!is.null(input$year)) {
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$`Year by Item`, ", "), function(x) any(input$year %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$Subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "geo_units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$`Geographic units`, ", "))))), selected = input$geo_units)
    }
if(!is.null(input$geo_units)){
      filtered_dat <- filtered_dat[sapply(strsplit(filtered_dat$`Geographic units`, ", "), function(x) any(input$geo_units %in% x)),]
      updateSelectInput(session, "subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$Subject, ", "))))), selected = input$subject)
      updateSelectInput(session, "year", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(filtered_dat$`Year by Item`, ", "))))), selected = input$year)
    }

output$ex1 <- DT::renderDT({
      DT::datatable(filtered_dat, escape=FALSE)
      
    }, filter = "none")
    
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

but using that same method doesn't work here. I am still a beginner to Shiny, and any help is most appreciated! Here is my current code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Language selection dropdown
  selectInput("lang", "Language", choices = c("English", "Français")),
  
  # Subject/sujet filter dropdown
  uiOutput("subject"),
  
  # Census Year(s) covered by item/Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item filter dropdown
  uiOutput("year"),
  
  #Geographic units/Unités géographiques filter dropdown
  uiOutput("units"),
  
  # Full data table
  DT::DTOutput('ex1')
  
)

# SERVER ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({ 
    # Generate the subject/sujet filter dropdown based on the selected language
    output$subject <- renderUI({
      if (input$lang == "English") {
        selectInput("subj", "Subject", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat_en$Subject, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      } else {
        selectInput("subj", "Sujet", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat_fr$Sujet, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      }
    })
    
    # Generate the year filter dropdown based on the selected language
    output$year <- renderUI({
      if (input$lang == "English") {
        selectInput("yr", "Census Year(s) covered by item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat_en$`Census Year(s) covered by item`, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      } else {
        selectInput("yr", "Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat_fr$`Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item`, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      }
    })
    
    #Generate the unit filter dropdown based on the selected language
    output$units <- renderUI({
      if (input$lang == "English") {
        selectInput("units", "Geographic units", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat_en$`Geographic units`, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      } else {
        selectInput("units", "Unités géographiques", choices = c("", sort(unique(unlist(strsplit(dat_fr$`Unités géographiques`, ", "))))), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
      }
    })
    
    # Filter the appropriate dataset based on the selected language, subject/sujet and year
    filtered_data <- reactive({
      if (input$lang == "English") {
        subset(dat_en, Subject %in% input$subj & `Census Year(s) covered by item` %in% input$yr & `Geographic units` %in% input$units)
      } else {
        subset(dat_fr, Sujet %in% input$subj & `Année(s) de recensement couverte(s) par l’item` %in% input$yr & `Unités géographiques` %in% input$units )
      }
    })
    
    # Display the filtered dataset
    output$ex1 <- DT::renderDT({
      DT::datatable(filtered_data(), escape=FALSE)
    })
    })
  
})

# Run the Shiny app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Some things to note: dat_en and dat_fr are in my environment when I run this app from R. I have also tried loading it in the app using the load() function as they are also stored as .RData files in my directory (same directory as where the app is located). I have also tried saving the data as .RDS files and reading them in using readRDS() but that also didn't work. Basically, I'm not sure if its the file reading that's the issue or if my code is overwriting itself somewhere and thus not displaying the data.

Thank you!

Comment: Difficult to help without a sample data set, but my approach would be to have some data pre-cleaning, where you make sure that both data sets have the same column. Then you could even put it into the same data.frame and everythings seems to be so much easier.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need everything in separate datasets due to them being in different languages. I don't think it's an issue with the filtering, but the fact that the data isn't being displaying in the mainPanel.